# Distance to nearest palindrome

Tags: palindrome

I'd like an algorithm to provide some kind of measure of how symmetrical a string is.In looking through previous questions, I found one on finding the number of letters that need to be added to a string to turn it into a palindrome. This is close to what I'm looking for but too restrictive in the set of allowable editing operations.

My motivation for this is that I'd like to make an improved version of a video that I put on Youtube called "Numbers are Colorful" The video shows Golden Ratio bases and a couple other related systems using irrational bases. Surprisingly, one system is to begin with completely symmetrical. but the others exhibit partial symmetry which I would like to highlight.

Comment: Do you want to consider adding or subtracting letters to make the string symmetrical? A straightforward comparison of letters about the centre point would provide a measure of symmetry. If you do want to consider abcb as "quite symmetrical" then the fact that you need to only add one 'a' to the string to make it completely symmetrical is somewhat important. Otherwise you would compare [a]{b}{c}[b] and see that it's totally asymmetrical.

Comment: Consider: 1001010.0010101. It seems quite symmetrical since for each positive digit, there is a corresponding negative digit which is not "too far" from where it ought to be. So an operation like moving a digit a little to the left or right seems to be called for. With adding and subtracting letters as a basic operation, you could delete a letter from one edge of the string and add a new one to the other edge. In other words, there needs to be a notion of locality.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. I still don't understand what your measure of symmetry is. Is that number binary? I know some people think in binary but I don't by default. They are equivalent by circular shift to the left, it's not symmetric. Could you please update your question with a few more examples to make it clear? You have to clarify **exactly** what you consider to be "symmetric" before anyone can help you with this.

Comment: Answering in reverse order: No, binary is base 2. The Golden ratio is an irrational number approx 1.618. Oddly, although the base is irrational, integers can be represented exactly. Have a look at Golden Ratio Base in Wikipedia.

Comment: Second part: My question asks, "Is there a definition of nearness to symmetry, along with a corresponding algorithm, which I might consider using?" So it's an open ended question, but not at all an unreasonable one. Anyone can see that the world is full of nearly symmetrical objects. How can this nearness to symmetry be measured?

Comment: Here's how to count to 10 in a symmetrical number representation:

Let b=(3+sqrt(5))/2.  And let a(n)  be A001906(n) at oeis.org, offset so that a(-1) = 0,  a(0) = 1, a(1) = 3, etc


1 = 1 = a(0)

2 = 2 = 2a(0) 

3 = b^1 + b^-1 = a(1) + a(-1)

4 = b^1 + 1 + b^-1 = a(1) + a(0) + a(-1)

5 = b^1 + 2 + b^-1 = etc (a-forms are palindromes just like b forms)

6 = 2b^1 + 2b^-1

7 = b^2 + b^-2

8 = b^2 + 1 + b^-2

9 = b^2 + 2 + b^-2

10 = b^2 + b^1 + b^-1 + b^-2

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for repetition or symmetry? So far I have seen no example that points to symmetry only repetition. 1001010.0010101 is not symmetrical. They are related by a circular shift, i.e. take the first set of digits [1001010], shift it to the left by 1 [0010101] and now you have the right side.

Unless you make it clear what you are trying to identify, this question is too poorly defined to give a sensible answer. If you really mean symmetrical, show me an example of symmetry. You might as well mean "I can see some interesting pattern here" which is so poorly defined it's difficult to quantify.

That said, digital signal processing is the sort of area you might look into for identifying interesting patterns. For example, if you are looking for repetition then I suggest you attempt to use an algorithm designed for detecting repeating patterns.

Consider the digits in your number to be an input signal. Perform frequency analysis on this signal to detect repeating sections of numbers. If you have a strong repeating component in your series of digits this should relate to a strong frequency component in your analysis. You can measure the strength of this pattern from identifying the fundamental frequency by performing the Fourier transform, and summing all of the harmonics for the most significant frequency bin. Divide this by the total energy of the signal and this will give you a measure between 0 and 1 for how "repetitive" the signal is, and will also identify the periodicity of the signal. You may be better off using time-domain algorithms like Autocorrelation, AMDF, or the YIN estimator. (Particularly AMDF)

A similar approach can be adopted if you were to consider actual symmetry (i.e. the numbers are still very similar when you reverse them).Take your input number, create a new signal by reversing it, and then measure their "sameness" at each discrete phase. If you have a digit of length N you could consider padding it with 0's to the length 2N before performing the comparison of the signal with it's inverted self, to consider the possibility of digits lying outside the length of the number.

The time-domain techniques are more likely to work because they are not affected so much by discontinuities. They do literally compare "sameness" of a signal by either computing the difference of all the points at each phase or multiplying the numbers together at each phase. In the subtraction case you hope to get to 0 when they are similar. In the multiplication case you hope to get a peak in the function when the numbers are back in phase. They are however more prone to noise (which in this context means the numbers which aren't quite right).

Comment: A perfectly symmetric number system is described by  Christiane Froughy, On multiplicatively dependent linear numeration systems, and periodic points", R.A.I.R.O. Theoretical Informatics and Applications 36 (2002) 293-314. Other number representations are similar but "not quite so symmetric." These number systems represent numbers as sequences of discrete digits, so signal processing is wrong. Counting 1-9 in Golden Ratio Base (see Wikipedia) with radix  pt omitted: 1, 1001, 10001, 10101, 10001001, 10100001, 100000001, 100010001, 100100101, 100100101. Both palindromes and "near misses."

Comment: In my "Numbers are Colorful" YouTube video http://bit.ly/y5pjv7, you can see the perfectly symmetrical numbers in the third column.

I've now found some relevant literature by Googling "Imperfect Symmetry Measures." Citing from Zabrodsky et al "Continuos Similarity Measures: "we argue that the treatment of natural phenomena in terms of either/or when it comes to a symmetry characteristic property, may become restrictive to the extent
that some of the details of phenomenological observations and of their theoretical interpretation may be lost. Some objects are more symmetrical than others"